# stringbuffer.reverse() is throwing UnsupportedOperationException:not supported yet

Tags: java

`stringbuffer.reverse()` is throwing `UnsupportedOperationException:not supported yet`

A few years ago this code was running fine, but now it's not working.
Has this method gone obsolete?

Comment: Please post the *actual* error message, as well as the version of Java you are using. There is nothing in the Javadoc to suggest this behavior; and it doesn't happen in [this ideone code](http://ideone.com/04fTck).

Comment: Please post your code so we can review it.

Comment: Additionally, unless you have a compelling reason to use `StringBuffer`, use `StringBuilder` instead.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuffer was replaced more than ten years ago from Java 5.0 but it still works just fine.  This error doesn't appear anywhere in the source for this class.

Is it possible you are using Java 1.0?